# Suppose $\|A+C \, \cos\pi z\| \leq e^{\|z\|}$, then $C = 0$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $\|A+C \, \cos\pi z\| \leq e^{\|z\|}$, then $C = 0$, where $A$ and $C$ are constants.  I have no clue why this should be true. My attempt is to view $2 \, \cos\pi z = e^{i\pi z} + e^{-i \pi z}$, then invoke triangle inequality, which does not shed any lights on this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Look at what happens when $z=it$ with $t\gg 0$.  If $C\neq 0$, then $\frac12 C\exp(\pi t)$ is the dominating term, and its magnitude grows faster than $\exp(t)$.